# Why some data are not displayed after editing source used by ngFor?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm playing around with Angular 6 now.

So what I have is an array of objects which I want to show via ngFor. 
From html page, I can do 2 different operations - add a new item to that array and remove an item from there.

What happens is that sometimes adding new items is causing already existing items to disappear from the view representation.

More exactly I have a scenario when this happens (it is also depicted on screenshot which attached):

1. Add a couple of items, so I have in total of 5 items in an array with displayed values "a","b","c","d",null
2. Remove item "c", then item "b" (so now I have "a","d",null)
3. Set value of last item (now I have "a","b","e")
4. Add new item. This is where a problem began. Item was added to the array, but at the same time value "d" stopped being displayed after this. Now the weird thing is that value "d" is actually still in a model (the last log on the screenshot), but it just not displayed.

To be honest not even sure how to start debugging this.

[image: Screenshot]

Adding new item code:

```js
  addItem () {
    var newItem = new CardItem(String(++this.itemCount), null);
    console.log("Created new item: "+JSON.stringify(newItem));

    this.testCard.back.push(newItem);
    console.log("Items after adding new option: "+JSON.stringify(this.testCard.back));
  }
```

Removing item code:

```js
  removeAnswer (itemIndex: string) { 
    if (itemIndex!=null) {
      var index = this.testCard.back.findIndex(answ => answ.id == itemIndex);
      console.log("Index of item to be removed: ["+index+"]. Object to be removed: ["+JSON.stringify(this.testCard.back[index])+"]");

      this.testCard.back.splice(index,1);
      console.log("Item after removal: "+JSON.stringify(this.testCard.back));
    } else {
      console.debug("Can't remove item, index is missed. ["+itemIndex+"].");
    }
  }
```

```html
    <mat-form-field *ngFor="let cardBack of testCard.back; let i = index; let first = first; let last = last">
      <input matInput placeholder="Item {{i+1}}" name="item{{i+1}}" [(ngModel)]="cardBack.item" >
      <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="removeItem(cardBack.id)">close</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Thanks everyone in advance!

**Added**

I fixed an issue by adding `trackBy` to my NgFor (added as an answer). However, I do not understand why did it work in one case but didn't work in another case.

So I tried to implementations of trackBy function. The one which works simply returns index value which was passed to the function. The implementation which didn't work was using unique `back.id` value, but it didn't work somehow. I thought that for trackBy function we need some unique identifier for our object which wouldn't change so that is why I tried to use back.id - it is generated once and doesn't change after that. 
On the other hand, after we adding/removing items from NgFor $index value will change every time so the same item will be tracked by different ids (which still will be unique).

So in both cases, unique values will be returned by a function. Why does it work in case of using `$index` in `trackBy` function but doesn't work when I'm trying to use a unique identifier (`back.id`) which is part of an object?

Comment: I created a stackblitz based off your code and it is working perfectly fine. https://angular-jwwfnh.stackblitz.io. Made some corrections since the method names in your shared code and template were not matching.

Comment: Did you change the default `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `onPush`?

Comment: @Batajus, no I didn't override it.

Comment: @ashish.gd, I beilive that you are using Angular 7 in your project. As I mentioned I'm using Angular 6. I'll try to update to Angular 7 and will get back with an answer here.

Comment: @ashish.gd I tried it with Angular 7 but surprisingly it didn't work either for me. The thing which fixed it was adding `trackBy` function which tracked elements by index. Before fixing it I've noticed one weird thing. Even though input value disappeared for "Item 2" it was still shown correctly in element property called `ng-reflect-model` which as far as I understood is for debugging purposes and supposed to display a value which has to be used by `ngModel`.

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed by adding `trackBy` function to `ngFor` which tracks items by index.
So basically I replaced next code:

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let cardBack of testCard.back; let i = index; let first = first; let last = last">
```

with:

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let cardBack of testCard.back; let i = index; trackBy: trackBackBy">
```

where function trackBackBy looks like:

```
trackBackBy (index, back) {
    return index;
}
```

Do not have an answer though for why adding new element made 2nd element's value to disappear (value of property `ng-reflect-model` was actually correct all the time). Would appreciate any help here at least what to look for.

I also tried using `back.id` in `trackBackBy` function but it didn't work somehow. I thought that for `trackBy` function we need some identifier for our object which wouldn't change so that is why I tried to use `back.id` - it is generated once and doesn't change after that. 
On the other hand, after we adding/removing items from `NgFor` `$index` value will change every time so the same item will be tracked by different ids (which still will be unique).

*So in both cases, unique values will be returned by a function. Why does it work in case of using $index in `trackBy` function but doesn't work when I'm trying to use a unique identifier (back.id) which is part of an object?*